# R works only with sudo

Tags: sudo, root, r

I installed R on UBUNTU 16.04 from source code with this:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

I know that `sudo` in last line wasn't necessary. But I used. Now My `R` works only when I enter `R` with `sudo` or in root mode.

Now the Question is How can I make `R` runs without `sudo`?

Comment: To install globally, you do need `sudo` with `make install`. Typically, this does not result in an installation that requires `sudo` to run.

Comment: Thanks @Zanna. So why this happens?

Comment: Based on your solution (which I upvoted because it's safe and appropriate) I suspect it was because you ran `R` with `sudo` once, causing root to become owner of the config files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I used `sudo` to run `R`, root became the owner of my `R` files. So I used this:

```
sudo chown Myname /home/Myname/ -R
```

and it worked without `sudo`.